# $\xi \frac{1 - \xi^{n+1}}{1 - (1 - \xi)} = 1 - \xi^{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ 0 < \xi < 1$. Then I've been told that this inequality holds true, but it doesn't seem obvious to me and I don't see how the equalities were reached. I think it might be a geometric series, but I am not sure.

$$\xi + \xi(1-\xi) + \xi(1-\xi)^2 + \dots + \xi(1-\xi)^n = \frac{1 - \xi^{n+1}}{1 - (1 - \xi)} = 1 - \xi^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have:
$$\xi + \xi(1-\xi) + \xi(1-\xi)^2 + \dots + \xi(1-\xi)^n$$
$$=\xi \frac{1-(1-\xi)^{n+1}}{1-(1-\xi)}$$

$$=1-(1-\xi)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just that $1-(1- \xi)$ is equal to $\xi$ and therefore on the left-hand side you have the same non-zero value on the numerator and denominator and therefore it's equal to 1 and you get the right-hand side?

Or if you're talking about the first equality it's due to the geometric progression formula (not geometric series). Keep in mind the sum has $n$ terms and not infinite.